# Why would SQL Server get a database stuck in DATABASE_SNAPSHOT_CREATION?

Tags: sql-server, logging, diskspace

I've a database in a production server which has a log that is getting enormous, while trying to understand the reason, I've issued this query:

```
SELECT name, log_reuse_wait_desc FROM sys.databases
```

The database in question has DATABASE_SNAPSHOT_CREATION, and even tough the docs say it should be a momentary state, it's been in this state for 10 mins. I'm guessing it's what's keeping the log from becoming manageable.

How can I fix this?

PS: I'm using the SIMPLE recovery mode.

Comment: Do you have a lot of indexes? and/or is the table very large? Sometimes it takes a while to port all the indexes over - to create those over a large number of rows

Comment: Yes, but I don't think that's what's causing this. I've restored a backup in my development notebook, and the logs are correctly sized. It's got a 1Gb mdf file, and 5Gb ldf now...I'm sure there's something wrong.

Comment: A large transaction log only means that the checkpoint isn't truncating it fast enough - you can see how much of it actually being used by looking at the 'shrink db' option from the DB menu...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK - Try running DBCC SQLPERF(LOGSPACE).  That will tell you how much of that log file is actually being used.

Comment: It appears less than 0.3% is being used...that can't be right! I'm wary of doing a SHRINK FILE (only because I don't know the performance implications of that...). Shouldn't have bad consequences in the LOG file, right?

Comment: That may be right - especially because you are in SIMPLE recovery. At some point, there was a large transaction, index rebuild, etc. that caused the file to grow. It's too bad performance-wise to shrink the log, since it writes sequentially, and it will only be keeping a tiny amount of active log.

Comment: So it won't ever be small again? Wouldn't a backup return it to a saner size?

Comment: No - it will never shrink unless you explicitly shrink it. It will just leave the remaining space in the file unused (if it doesn't need it).  A backup will force a CHECKPOINT, which will reduce the "used" portion of the log, but the file size will not change.

Comment: OK, so it probably is part of normal operation, it won't grow (not when it has more than 97% of unused space) and it won't shrink. The question is misleading by now, but I'll mark this as an answer. Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, 
now it is sorted out :)

-> database on simple recovery mode, showing up this DATABASE_SNAPSHOT_CREATION on the log_reuse_wait_desc.

what I did to sort it out was to run the script below:

```
use Databasename
go

checkpoint
```

the "checkpoint" part I run many times.
after that no more DATABASE_SNAPSHOT_CREATION.

The scripts that I have used in my quest are the following:

```
DBCC SQLPERF(LOGSPACE)

select log_reuse_wait_desc, * from sys.databases
where log_reuse_wait_desc != 'NOTHING'


SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_requests

checkpoint
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any large transactions open? Database snapshots are always taken of the database in a consistent state.  If a large transaction has been running for, say, 10 minutes, the transaction has to be rolled back in the snapshot before the snapshot can be complete.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_requests
```

The above query can tell you what's running at the time it is run.

Comment: I'm seeing various system requests, all with the same start time (from a month ago, so I guess they are all correct)...user requests are not many and they are short lived.

Comment: I thought that snapshot referred to either READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT isolation level or SNAPSHOT isolation (which I'm not using in this database)...what is DATABASE_SNAPSHOT_CREATION referring too?

Comment: No - READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT deals with individual data pages and tempdb. A database snapshot is created explicitly (via a command) or when DBCC CHECKDB is run on the database. If you haven't kicked off a snapshot, I would suspect CHECKDB got hung during the snapshot creation phase.

Comment: Aha! That maybe it! I have an automated CHECKDB run each night and send me failure reports...any idea how can I confirm that?

Comment: You can run SELECT s.session_id, s.login_name, r.command FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions s ON r.session_id = s.session_id

Comment: Look for the account that is runs the CHECKDB

Comment: I don't have any...all I see is BRKR EVENT HNDLR,BRKR TASK,CHECKPOINT,LAZY WRITER,LOCK MONITOR,LOG WRITER,RESOURCE MONITOR,SELECT,SIGNAL HANDLER,TASK MANAGER,TRACE QUEUE TASK,XE DISPATCHER,XE TIMER commands. The SELECT is short lived, the rest appear to be system commands...

Comment: Well, as M.R. said, the DATABASE_SNAPSHOT_CREATION had nothing to do with it, as now the log_reuse_wait_desc says NOTHING. Still don't know why the log is so big...